# what does increasing the difficulty for Gwent do, in The Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

If raising the difficulty for Gwent increases the difficulty of AI tactics, I would like the challenge. However, if it simply gives the AI better cards, than I would prefer to start the game on a lower level of difficulty.

So what does increasing the difficulty of Gwent actually do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know it only increases AI card quality. You'll find early game merchants sporting a Geralt or Ciri.

I haven't noticed Gwent becoming any harder in the late game, when I had a killer deck as well.

Comment: well thanks, I think its kind of easy right? I have limited cards no heroes and I am winning most rounds I increased the difficulty and I won the braon. I know there are better opponents out there ...

Comment: @MegatonSettler Yes, if you're competent it's rather easy to win against most opponents. I think I had to revisit my tactics and actually improve my game close to final gwent competition of the game. Oh, and sometimes a random merchant might get a killer deck, not sure what governs that.